# Auto-update field after specific amount of time only when specific conditions are met

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Mongodb has an option to set TTL on documents.

I would like to know if there is a similar feature that allows the update of a specific field after a specific amount of time.

Basically what I want to achieve is update the field STATUS of a document from PENDING to EXPIRED after a specific amount of time (only if it was PENDING).

I know I could use cronjobs, but first I want to check whether it's possible natively with Mongodb.

Furthermore, is it possible to set the TTL with condition? Like deleting a document after X days only if STATUS is EXPIRED?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the TTL with condition, I found that there is an option called "partialFilterExpression" that you can add to the index.

For example the following will delete a document after 5 minutes only if status is "PENDING"

```
db.mymodel.createIndex({ createdAt: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 300, partialFilterExpression: { status: 'PENDING' } })
```

Answer (score 1):

> what I want to achieve is update the field STATUS of a document from PENDING to EXPIRED after a specific amount of time

Not achievable today, you have to create your own script

> Furthermore, is it possible to set the TTL with condition? Like
> deleting a document after X days only if STATUS is EXPIRED?

I recommend you that the script that set the status also set `readyToBeDeletedSince: Date` and that you put your TTL on that field.